# Android why do my adfonic interstitials appear for only a second then dissapear

Tags: java, android, interstitial

So as question suggests im trying to get full screen ads working, and i have it so they do appear but they only stay there for 4 seconds or so but then dissapear

what am i not doing/ doing wrong, i cant seem to find any documentation from adfonic and all of admobs seems too different to be of any help.

```
public class AdPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button Close;

private final static String TAG = "Testing";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ad_layout);

    final AdfonicView adView = (AdfonicView) findViewById(R.id.adfonicView);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedAd() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onReceivedAd()");

            adView.showInterstitial();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPresentScreen() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onPresentScreen()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNoFill() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onNoFill()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onNetworkError()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onLeaveApplication() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onLeaveApplication()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidRequest() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onInvalidRequest()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInternalError() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onInternalError()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onDismissScreen() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onDismissScreen()");

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AdListener onClick()");

        }
    });
```

This is the layout

```
<com.adfonic.android.AdfonicView
    xmlns:adfonic="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.adfonic.android"
    android:id="@+id/adfonicView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    adfonic:adfonic_adslot_id="######"
    adfonic:language="en"
    adfonic:refresh_ad="true"
    adfonic:refresh_time="30" />
```

Comment: Hi @ryan, can you manage to disable the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.adfonic.com/index.php/Android_SDK

With Adfonic at the moment for interstitial ads the timeout is 4 seconds.

I believe in the next update of the SDK they are adding the capability to setting the timeout for your interstitial ads.